# Why didn't Tony use E.D.I.T.H. against Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

When Thanos and his army attacked Avengers HQ in *Avengers: Endgame*, E.D.I.T.H. was in existence because Tony

> died in the battle

so he couldn't build it after the battle. Why didn't he use E.D.I.T.H. in the battle?

I know that E.D.I.T.H. stands for *Even Dead, I'm The Hero*. It means that Tony built it to gift it to someone else through his will. But, Thanos' attack was an emergency situation. E.D.I.T.H.'s drones and missiles with coordinated intelligence could certainly prove useful against Thanos and his army.

Why didn't Tony use E.D.I.T.H.?

Comment: Related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101919/why-didnt-tony-stark-use-this-system-earlier

Answer (score 1):

Tony had access to everything Edith did via his suit. The ai wouldn’t have added to the fight enough to be a viable reason to use the glasses.

Comment: I think that the question is why didn't he deploy the drones and other weapons from the satellite, not why he didn't use the AI in the glasses

Comment: I’d assume it’s cuz they’d probably get in the way more so than they would help. Seeing as it was thanos and if it took so much work to kill him, some missiles wouldn’t do much.

Comment: `Seeing as it was thanos and if it took so much work to kill him, some missiles wouldn’t do much.` ~> Tony definitely didn't build E.D.I.T.H. for Earthly threats. He always talked about defence against aliens.